# Angular component property with type DataBindingDirective has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid, npm-package

I'm getting compilation error:

Property with type DataBindingDirective has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

```
@ViewChild(DataBindingDirective) dataBinding: DataBindingDirective;
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I suspect that it maybe related to the packages versions, because at stackblitz everything working fine (working example: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkdvup-odasxc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) ).

Bigger chunk of code:

```
export class NPEComponent implements OnInit {
  rowData$: Observable<Array<NPE>> = of([]);
  public filter$: Observable<CompositeFilterDescriptor | null>;
  @ViewChild(DataBindingDirective) dataBinding: DataBindingDirective;  // compilation error here

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.filter$ = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
      map(params => params['name']),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(searchTerm => {
        if (!searchTerm) return null;

        return (<CompositeFilterDescriptor>{
          logic: 'or',
          filters: [ buildFilterItem('organizationName', searchTerm) ]
        })
      }),
      //tap(() => console.log('filter been assigned')),
      //tap(() => this.dataBinding.skip = 0),
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rowData$ = this.NPEService.apiNPEGet();
  }
```

versions from packages.json :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.5",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^11.1.0",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^11.0.3",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^13.2.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^13.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^13.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^13.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^8.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^3.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^7.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^7.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^7.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^5.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^7.3.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-indicators": "^3.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^10.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^4.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^4.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^7.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^4.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^4.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^7.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.17.1",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "run-script-os": "^1.1.6",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.5",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^13.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.29",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.19",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "schematics-scss-migrate": "^1.3.15",
    "typescript": "~4.6.3"
  }
}
```

In PowerShell:

```
>ng --version
Angular CLI: 13.3.10
Node: 18.13.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.19.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 13.3.12
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.10
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.10
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.10
@angular/cli                    13.3.10
@schematics/angular             13.3.10
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.6.4
```

Answer (score 1):

The described behavior is related to a TypeScript strict configuration.One simple way to avoid it will be to place an non-null assertion operator "!":

```
@ViewChild(DataBindingDirective) dataBinding!: DataBindingDirective;
```

The error isn't present in StackBlitz as the project is missing the strict type check configurations in the tsconfig.json file.

Comment: And if I'm using it in the constructior, it tells me that dataBinding is undefind. I wonder, how to set it to proper value after initializing/loading grid with data..